# Returning Strings from a file between 2 specified strings in java

Tags: java

I've been searching the web and I can't seem to find a working solution.
I have a file containing theses lines:

```
Room 1
Coffee
Iron
Microwave
Room_end
Room 2
Coffee
Iron 
Room_end
```

I want to print all Strings between Room 1 and Room_end. I want my code to start when it find Room 1, print line after Room 1 and stop when it get to the first Room_end it find.

```
private static String LoadRoom(String fileName) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            result = reader.lines()
                    .dropWhile(line -> !line.equals("Room 1"))
                    .skip(1)
                    .takeWhile(line -> !line.equals("Room_end"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create " + fileName + ": " + ie.getMessage());
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(result.get(i).getname());//error on getname because it cant work with Strings
        }
    }



    class Model {

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

I am able to get a method to print all Strings of the file but not specific range of Strings. I also tried to work with Stream. My code feel quite messy, but I've been working on it for a while an it seems it only get messier.

Comment: type String has no method getname (nor getName)

Comment: You code won't compile.  It's not returning a string.  If the method is supposed to return a string, then there's no reason for it to print the string.  Either it return the string, or print the string but with void return type.  I think using stream is an overkill for this.  Why not just use a scanner to read line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched my code and used this:

```
    private static String loadRoom(String fileName) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = null; //we start with empty info
            String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator"); //make a new line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //consider if the line is empty or not
                if (line.equals("Room 1")) { //condition start on the first line being "Room 1"
                    line = reader.readLine(); // read the next line, "Room 1" not added to stringBuilder
                    while (!line.equals("Room_end")) {    //check if line String is "Room_end"
                        stringBuilder.append(line);//add line to stringBuilder
                        stringBuilder.append(ls);//Change Line in stringBuilder
                        line = reader.readLine();// read next line
                    }
                }
                
            }
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Fixed it. stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1); wasn't at the right place.

Comment: Just a small thing, you can break out all loop after reach “Room end “, now it seems like it will read the whole file/to the end after finding Room end

Comment: Yes thank you, file I was testing with had only 2 rooms in it. While i plan to go around 180 to 370 rooms. Break will be useful thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem if you want to use lambda expression here:

lambda expressions are functional programming, and functional programming requires immutability, that means there should **not be state related issue**, you can call the function and give it same parameters and the result always will be the same, but **in your case, there should be a state indicating whether you should print the line or not**.

can you try this solution? I write it in python, but mainly it is just about a variable `should_print` that located outside of the scope

```
should_print = False
result = reader.lines()
for line in result:
    if line == "Room end":
        break
    if should_print:
        print(line)
    if line == "Room 1":
        should_print = True
```

keep a boolean value outside of the iteration, and check/update the value in each iteration

Comment: Your solution will print "Room 1" which is not what he want.  You should make the last if to elif.

Comment: thanks, that is my mistake, I changed it, I want to point out that PO should not implement this problem with stream/lambda expression, and I did not pay enough attention to the code

Comment: Thank you, i got lost into my coding. I will get back to the basic like you highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getRooms(String path) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
        sc.useDelimiter("(?=Room \\d+)|Room_end");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            Scanner lines = new Scanner(sc.next());
            String room = lines.nextLine().trim();
            List<String> roomFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
            while (lines.hasNextLine()) {
                roomFeatures.add(lines.nextLine());
            }
            if (room.length() > 0) {
                result.put(room, roomFeatures);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

is one way of doing it for your 'rooms file' though it should really be made more OO by making a `Room` bean to hold the data. Output with your file: `{Room 2=[Coffee, Iron ], Room 1=[Coffee, Iron, Microwave]}`

Comment: A minor addition, since Java 11 we have [`String.stip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) and it's flavors as a replacement to `trim()`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Interesting. That's the first time I've come across that. The difference is subtle but I'm having a hard time thinking of when that might be useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a scanner and a flag.  You may choose to break the loop when it reads "Room_end"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
   private static String loadRoom(String fileName) throws IOException { 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean print = false;
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
           String line = s.nextLine();
           if      (line.equals("Room 1"))   print = true;
           else if (line.equals("Room_end")) print = false;
           else if (print) sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
   }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
       try {
          String content = loadRoom("content.txt");
          System.out.println(content);
       }catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```